# Facebook connect situation

Tags: php, facebook

My app is using its internal registration system for users to signup and login...

I am now checking out the idea of integrating Facebook Connect into my app but i have come to a situation that i think i need some sort of help...

So **users** in my app **upon registration** have to **select** a **username** and **email address** which **are unique**.

What will happen if a user tries to connect via Facebook and that user already exists? their email for example? or what will happen if that user doesnt have a username? can i show them error messages depending in their situation?

Also if the user doesnt have a username on facebook but has an email address that is not registered in my system do i have to show them a new inputfield for them to type in their username before they can access the website further?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of these scenarios have been explained in [registration flows](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/user_registration/flows/), specifically

**My site uses Facebook and my own Registration**

[image: Registration Flow]

Comment: ok i get it regarding same email situation... i will simply change the current user ID to the facebook UID... what about the username? what if the user trying to log in from facebook doesnt have a username? do i show them a form to add one until they can see the site? also if they have a username i guess i will have to merge it to his account as i did with UID

Comment: @fxuser Use the email as unique in terms of dupe users between your registration and Facebook. If they don't have a username, suggest one based on their name (e.g. how Twitter sign up works). So if your site is dependent on unique usernames after the user has logged with the FB plugin and has a username, autocomplete it (if not taken) in your registration tool, if not leave it blank. So, a user starts with the FB plugin, then you check your database for the user email address then send to your site's registration page with username field autocompleted if they have a Facebook username

Comment: thats a thought i had and it seems to be ideal for this situtation... thanks phwd

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

If user connects by Facebook, but don't have account on your website, you should redirect him to page where he needs to fill required data (username and anything else what you want). Don't let him go until he fills all required data.

If user connects by Facebook and this email has account on your website, you should link this Facebook ID to this account.

So you should do unique emails to users and they should login with it. It would be unique identifier.